# Angularjs. Does it real to get $valid property for element through ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm sorry if answer on my question already was somewhere here, i tried to find it, but all what i got - not my case.

Notice: i'm working with django 1.4 so i change angular syntax for no conflict with django-template, so {$ var $} = {{ var }}.

How in can do this:

```
<form name="testForm">
<table><tr ng-repeat="field in contrller.fields"><td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{$ field.label $}" name="{$ field.name $}" ng-model="field.value" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" ng-class="{'has-error': field.$invalid}">
</td></td></table>
```

In this case i can't got field.$invalid or field.$valid property. 
I know i can do it through method: ng-class="controller.getClasses(field)" but if exist some possibility for avoid it - i prefer this one.

Comment: You would need to use [ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) to get it working properly

Comment: It is can work, but i need to wrap few elements with unique names. I feel it too excessively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$invalid` property is not set on the object you have in your `ng-repeat` but accessed via the name of the form and the name of the input field.

You need something like

```
ng-class="{'has-error': 'testForm.' + field.name + '.$invalid'}
```

To stop required fields to have a visible error when the page is loaded, you can also use the `$dirty` property.

```
ng-class="{'has-error': 'testForm.' + field.name + '.$invalid' && 'testForm.' + field.name + '.$dirty'}
```

Comment: It's work but not like i expected. Class now adds when page render (field is required), but not remove when validation really passed. Is it normal? Or i did something wrong?

Comment: @master_alf Yes, you can check on the `$dirty` property. It is false as long as the user has not changed the value of the input field. See edit.

Comment: Or i can't understand something, or it doesn't work anyway. I made example in fiddle, could you please correct it? http://jsfiddle.net/master_alf/47mr1omw/

Comment: Hm.. I've noe idea what's going wrong in that fiddle, sorry.